# How do I Base58 Checked encode / decode an address in C#? What does "normalize leading zeros" mean?

Tags: development, public-key, c#, base58check

I am trying to encode and decode a Base58 address in C#.  The following function is a start, but it has a few issues:

- This code does not [normalize leading zeros](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding#Creating_a_Base58Check_string) (what does that look like?)
- If this method is repeatedly called in rapid succession many string objects will be created, putting pressure on the GC

**.NET 4.5 Code**

*Note add a reference to System.Numerics*

```
BigInteger  bi =  System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6", NumberStyles.HexNumber);

string b58 = EncodeBase58(bi);
Console.WriteLine(b58 + Environment.NewLine + "16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM");

   /// .... SNIP

   public static String sBase58Alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static String EncodeBase58(BigInteger numberToShorten)
    {
        // WARNING: Beware of bignumber implementations that clip leading 0x00 bytes, or prepend extra 0x00 
        // bytes to indicate sign - your code must handle these cases properly or else you may generate valid-looking
        // addresses which can be sent to, but cannot be spent from - which would lead to the permanent loss of coins.)


        // Base58Check encoding is also used for encoding private keys in the Wallet Import Format. This is formed exactly
        // the same as a Bitcoin address, except that 0x80 is used for the version/application byte, and the payload is 32 bytes
        // instead of 20 (a private key in Bitcoin is a single 32-byte unsigned big-endian integer). Such encodings will always
        // yield a 51-character string that starts with '5', or more specifically, either '5H', '5J', or '5K'.   https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding
        const int sizeWalletImportFormat = 51;

        char[] result = new char[33];

        int i = 0;
        while (numberToShorten >= 0 && result.Length > i)
        {
            var lNumberRemainder = BigInteger.Remainder(numberToShorten, (BigInteger)sBase58Alphabet.Length);
            numberToShorten = numberToShorten / (BigInteger)sBase58Alphabet.Length;
           result[result.Length - 1- i] = sBase58Alphabet[(int)lNumberRemainder] ;
           i++;
        }

        return new string(result);
    }
    //public static long DecodeBase58(String base58StringToExpand)
    //{
    //    long lConverted = 0;
    //    long lTemporaryNumberConverter = 1;

    //    while (base58StringToExpand.Length > 0)
    //    {
    //        String sCurrentCharacter = base58StringToExpand.Substring(base58StringToExpand.Length - 1);
    //        lConverted = lConverted + (lTemporaryNumberConverter * sBase58Alphabet.IndexOf(sCurrentCharacter));
    //        lTemporaryNumberConverter = lTemporaryNumberConverter * sBase58Alphabet.Length;
    //        base58StringToExpand = base58StringToExpand.Substring(0, base58StringToExpand.Length - 1);
    //    }
    //}
```

Comment: Note that you can use BigInteger.DivRem to divide and get the remainder in one operation which is faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize leading zeros is [documented in this link,](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/File%3aPubKeyToAddr.png) namely this text at the bottom:

> In a standard base conversion, the 0x00 byte on the left would be
>   irrelevant (like writing 052 instead of 52) but in the BTC network the
>   left most zero chars are carried through the conversion. So for every
>   0x00 byte on the left end of the binary address, we will attach one
>   '1' character to the Base58 address.  This is why the main-network
>   addresses all start with 1.

The following code will address the GC issue with over-allocation and discarding of the String type, however it  **does not** properly handle the leading zero bytes.  I either need to find a list of expected lengths per type or some other approach.

```
    public static String sBase58Alphabet = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static String EncodeBase58(BigInteger numberToShorten)
    {
        // WARNING: Beware of bignumber implementations that clip leading 0x00 bytes, or prepend extra 0x00 
        // bytes to indicate sign - your code must handle these cases properly or else you may generate valid-looking
        // addresses which can be sent to, but cannot be spent from - which would lead to the permanent loss of coins.)


        // Base58Check encoding is also used for encoding private keys in the Wallet Import Format. This is formed exactly
        // the same as a Bitcoin address, except that 0x80 is used for the version/application byte, and the payload is 32 bytes
        // instead of 20 (a private key in Bitcoin is a single 32-byte unsigned big-endian integer). Such encodings will always
        // yield a 51-character string that starts with '5', or more specifically, either '5H', '5J', or '5K'.   https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding
        const int sizeWalletImportFormat = 51;

        char[] result = new char[33];

        Int32 iAlphabetLength = sBase58Alphabet.Length;
        BigInteger iAlphabetLength2 = BigInteger.Parse(iAlphabetLength.ToString());

        int i = 0;
        while (numberToShorten >= 0 && result.Length > i)
        {
            var lNumberRemainder = BigInteger.Remainder(numberToShorten, iAlphabetLength2);
            numberToShorten = numberToShorten / iAlphabetLength;
           result[result.Length - 1- i] = sBase58Alphabet[(int)lNumberRemainder] ;
           i++;
        }

        return new string(result);
    }
```